# location monitoring in a iphone app

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

I am an newbie with iphone app development. I would like to capture location information without using GPS but only with Cell tower info and Wifi data. To enable this I am using the `CLLocationManager` to capture location information,

```
 self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
float latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
float longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
// NSTimeInterval is defined as double
NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: timeStamp];
NSLog(@"latitude %f and longitude %f", latitude, longitude );
NSLog(@"%d", [timeStampObj integerValue]);
NSMutableArray *numArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:latitude],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:longitude], timeStampObj,  nil];    
}
```

When I use the above code when the app is launched I see that the app requests for accessing location services. Once this is accepted, I am not sure if the app is making use of GPS to get the location information as I see a small arrow pointing out, which seems as though GPS is being used to obtain the location information, which is not what I require. I would want the location information to be captured using WiFi and Cell Tower information only.

Also is there a frequency in which this location information gets updated, as there is an initial update of location after that I do not see the location getting modified even after the phone is being continuously moved.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this:

```
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

You are only getting GPS uploads when a significant change happens (for example, when you move from a telephony tower to other).

You cannot choose if you want to use GPS or towers from the code.

Comment: thanks for sharing this but coming from an android back-ground I can select the provider I want to use in order to obtain the location information. If I use the Network_Provider the location information is obtained using Wifi and Cell Tower. With GPS_Provider I can specify that I can use GPS for location information. So is there a way for me to specify and use only WiFi and Cell tower info in order to get the location, without GPS ?

Comment: Not in iPhone, sorry!